# Change order of execution of bash command

Tags: bash

Is there a way in bash that can change the order of what gets executed first?
Just to give an example, similar to brackets in c/c++

```
a = (1+2)*3
```

---

An example command for bash that could use specified order of execution. Please don't take this example literally, its just an example to explain what I am asking.

```
kubectl exec -it my-pod-0 -- cat /etc/ssl/key > /tmp/key
```

I could want **2 different things** in such a case:

```
(kubectl exec -it my-pod-0 -- cat /etc/ssl/key) > /tmp/key    # first case
```

or

```
kubectl exec -it my-pod-0 -- (cat /etc/ssl/key > /tmp/key)    # second case
```

This is a small example but the command can go really complex and use something that can help specify the order of execution.

---

I am aware that I can use this.

```
kubectl exec -it my-pod-0 -- bash -c "cat /etc/ssl/key" > /tmp/key
```

to achieve a few cases like the first one above.
And the second case is the default behaviour.
On a side note, if someone knows other ways for this small example, its appreciated as well.

Comment: Shell commands (at least, most shell commands) aren't recursively defined as the composition of simpler commands, so it doesn't really make sense to talk about the order of execution in this way.

Comment: On the other hand, certain constructs necessarily impose an order: `foo $(bar)` requires `bar` to be run first, so that its output is available to be used as an argument for `foo`. Other things are explicitly asynchronous; in `foo | bar`, neither command is required to start before the other, and the two commands can and will run concurrently, with `foo` being suspended if `bar` isn't reading from the pipe buffer quickly enough and `bar` being suspended if `foo` isn't writing to the pipe buffer quickly enough.

Comment: You *might* be thinking of something like `a && b && c`, which is equivalent to `{ a && b; } && c`, but can be explicitly grouped like `a && { b && c; }` to change the meaning.